# Algorithm for effective connection resource management

Tags: algorithm, resources, constraints

difficult to look this up if it has been asked previously since I don't know the name for it. So here goes:

I'm making this server which connects to messaging gateways in order to send msgs.
A session with this gateway requires a username/password combo. This way the gateway knows who to bill.

Now I could have thousands of messages queued up to send, belonging for instance to 5 different username/password combos. However, the gateway is restricted that I only have say 2 connections open at the same time.

So effectively it is a question of supply and demand with constraints:

I have a gateway which can only handle N concurrent connections (username/pw combo)
I have X messages stacked up belonging to Y different of these connections

how do I, in a nice and clean way, efficiently manage these connections so that they sometimes give breathing space for other connections, perhaps even take into account priority, perhaps even allow multiple connections with the same username/password for extra speed (if it doesn't sit in the way of other queued connections)

Does anyone have a clue what kind of algorithms exist for this? So I can google for it.
Or perhaps someone already can give me some pointers.

I've given a few stabs at it myself, but I feel I'm still not yet creating an elegant solution, but somehow endup in long nested if statements

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another poster mentioned, you need a Priority Queue, though I suggest that you hybridize the priority queue with a queue-of-queues.

1. For each connection (username/password), create a simple LIFO queue. The module that receives messages should enqueue them for the appropriate user.
2. The dispatcher module should maintain a priority-sorted queue-of-queues. This implies that you have a function `priority(queue)` which calculates the priority for a given queue based on the number of messages, account priority, time since last send, etc. Implementing `priority(queue)` is left as an exercise to the reader.
3. The dispatcher's inner loop takes the N highest-priority queues off of the queue-of-queues, makes a connection to the gateway for each username/password, and sends all messages in those queues. The newly emptied queues go back into the queue-of-queues. Recalculate priority for all queues, rinse and repeat.

Ideally, the message-sending portion of step #3 could be multi-threaded.

An alternate implementation of step #3 would be to send messages from each queue until that queue's priority drops below the priority of the next waiting queue. However, this implies that you recalculate `priority(queue)` after every send, which may be more expensive than it's worth.

Comment: Ok... this sounds pretty sane actually. It doesn't allow yet for handling multiple connections for a username/pw (for sending stuff extra fast, if no other queues are available), but I don't think adding this is too difficult.

Comment: your alternate for step 3: recalcing for every message could result in switching a connection for every message sent. So thats not a good idea I think, since setting up a connection takes time. I think recalcing the queue every X minutes should be fine

Comment: just thinking.... since the queues still change/fillup. Is a priority queue really good? Priority queue implies that the priority of an element doesn't change since you insert it at the correct point. I might as well have a list which I sort everyX minutes according to some priority scheme. right?

Comment: You could think of the queue-of-queues as a list-of-queues, if you like. It's mostly just a question of terminology...

Comment: @reiner: When filling the priority queue, you have presumably done so using a reasonable algorithm.  If a new element appears that needs to be sent earlier, sent later, or sent along with elements already in the priority queue, you can assign the new element a priority to get it to the right place in the queue.  If you instead create a list that you resort from time-to-time, you will either have to "freeze" the list during resort (pausing the gateways) or have a rather complex algorithm that allows for elements to be taken by a gateway during the sort.

Comment: If you do resort the list, though, you should do it more often than every few minutes. I suggest that you do it every time you empty an active queue, so that you always get the highest-priority queue when it's time to rotate queues.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you want to implement a [Priority Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Since you have specific ideas about what message to prioritize over others, you would want an implementation that allows you to calculate a priority score for each queue entry.  Since you want to group messages sometimes, you would also need to be able to examine the queue when assigning priority to a new queue entry (for example, you might decide to set the priority of a new element equal to the priority of the newest existing element with the same username as long as no more than N elements already have that priority.

Given that you have a fixed number of outbound gateways, you would probably want one priority queue per gateway.  A routing component that takes a new message and determines which queue to place it on could examine elements in each existing queue to determine which one to best place it on (i.e. place it in the same queue as other elements with the same user ID) if that will optimize throughput.

If your gateway is even a little slower than the routing algorithm, you will have a net increase in speed by making the routing algorithm as clever as possible.

Comment: do you mean a priority queue of queues? So basically every possible username/pw connection is a queue with it's messages, and all these queues are in a priority queue? where the bottom X are enabled? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: My understanding of the requirement is that a given new element may be assigned to an existing queue based on the contents of each of the queues.  That is, the queue's for the gateway would not be LIFO, but rather you might want to select a gateway queue that already has elements with the same username and specifically assign the new element to that gateway queue (to minimize overhead associated with connecting a new user).  That's a bit different than what you describe.  Again it depends on exactly what the requirement is.

Comment: ... and when you assign the new element to an existing gateway (priority) queue, you would want to assign it the same priority as existing elements with the same username so they are processed in the same group.

Comment: ericj: the problem is not assigning the msgs to the correct queues. The problem lies in the fact that given 5 full queues, and the gateway which will only allow 2 of them sending at the same time. How to handle this properly.

Comment: @Reiner: He states 5 username/password combos and one gateway allowing max. 2 connections.  Place one priority queue in front of each gateway connection.  Place all incoming elements in a LIFO queue.  Have a router that takes elements off of the LIFO queue (with perhaps millions of messages) and picks one of the two priority queues in front of the two connections, favoring a queue that already has messages from the same user to minimize overhead to log off/log on with the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OS task scheduling and network scheduling algorithms. They try to solve a lot of similar problems of assigning timeslices of a limited resource to a larger number of consumers. There's a huge amount of research out there. In particular [weighted fair queueing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_fair_queuing) sounds like it might be useful for you.

Any particular choices depend heavily on what behavior you want your algorithm to have. For instance if you want to minimize latency for all queues you'll want to prioritize queues with the oldest messages and maybe give larger slices to longer queues.

On the other hand you might want to preempt someone doing large batch sends as their messages will have a long latency anyway and let queues with light usage through before the batch send.

Comment: thanks for the extra answer! I'll definitely give this a read